# Transparent image placed under/behind paragraph

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a simple webpage that has a sidebar and a main body. In the main body, I have some paragraphs. In two of the paragraphs, I'd like for a transparent image to appear under/behind the paragraphs. The image is *not* part of the background. I'd like to be able to adjust the size and position of the image (relative to the paragraphs) and also the image's transparency without affecting the settings for the main body (e.g., text opacity, width, etc.).

I've been searching on Google, but I'm unable to find anything close to what I hope to achieve. I don't have an example. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you give the code and the UI mockup what you want.

Comment: Share your code what you have tried.

Comment: The keywords are `position: absolute`/`position:fixed`. Try yourself first, try writing at least a simple example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want? If something you don't understand, you can comment or try searching those terms on google.

```css
.paragraph-with-bg {
  position:relative;
}
.paragraph-with-bg::before {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0;
  background:url("https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x150"); 
  opacity: .15;
  z-index: -1000;
}
```

```html
<p class="paragraph-with-bg">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
```

Comment: I had to change some things to my own liking, but this did the trick. THank you! :)

Comment: Actually, there is one issue: You have to zoom-in to see it, but the background image slightly changes the color (or opacity?) of the text that is directly over the image. I had to zoom-in quite a bit just to see it.

Comment: @BrittK You can try adding `z-index: -1000;` if it visualizes what you want. Because the image would definitely affect the visual of the paragraph, that's a little bit about `contrast`.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is, you want an image to appear behind the text. the text is not effected when you change the opacity of the image. here is a simple code I would suggest you to try

```
<div class="main-container">
<div class="img-behind-text">
<div class="text-upon-image">
<h1> your text here </h1>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.img-behind-text{backgroud:url("image.png"); opacity:"0.5";}
```

and further include your styling, setting the position of the image / division.

[Check here for more help](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_text)

Comment: This changes the opacity of the image, but it also changes the opacity of the text.

Comment: @BrittK Please check this out [link](https://jsfiddle.net/asadk6103/g5was7pr/1/)


I have set the background color of the text in the bottom left, try to change the opacity of
.container img {opacity:0.3;} to 0 and then check that the text opacity does not changes but the background image opacity changes

Comment: I'm not sure if that's exactly what I'm after. Sorry! I don't want the image to fill up the entire background where the paragraphs go, a background image. Isn't your code giving me a background image rather than an image placed under the text (but still over the background)?